# Write common methods in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

To develop a project where I am creating some methods which are common in all the controllers.

Before this I have used codeigniter and there I wrote MY_Controller class in core directory and then I extended the controller in all the controllers in controller directory.

Same I want to do inside `Laravel`. But I am confused that where should I write the common methods like `send_email`, `validate_captcha`, `ajax_file_upload` and other common methods which remains same across whole application.

So please suggest me a good way to define such a class or middleware.. What should one do to create that?

Comment: You should post what you ve already tried on order to achieve this. You have tons of possibilities and for each of your requirements it might be a different one. If you want to validate a captcha you can write a RequestValidator and extend it in your other validators, but you are not forced to use validators so you could aswell create your own controller and provide a validation method and let you other controllers extend it

Answer (score 0):

OK. Let me suggest some stuffs

1. Need to write methods which is apply to all Controllers. You
   can/should modify `App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`. Because all
   Controllers in Laravel extend it
2. Need to write class that available across whole application. It is
   never easier

**Step 1**: Write any class you want in `app` folder. And follow `psr-4` convention 
**Step 2**: Register to Laravel application
In `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`. In `register()` method. Add

```
$this->app->bind('bindname', function ($app) {
    return new \App\YourClass;
    // If you want to inject other class to YourClass contructor
    // return new \App\YourClass($app->make('otherbindname'));
});
```

**Step 3**: Use it. There are several ways to access YourClass in your **whole** application:

```
app()->make('bindname');

app('bindname');

app()['bindname'];

\App::make('bindname');

//etc
```